# How to read line into multiples files

Tags: python

i don't know how read a line based on criteria on multiples files with python this is my code:

```
def find_by_ruc(file, ruc):
  with open(file) as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        if ruc in line:
             yield line

source= "TUNGURAHUA.txt"
ruc = '1804464194001'
row = list(linea.split('\t') for linea in find_by_ruc(source, ruc))
print row
```

this code works perfect to find a row in one file the problem is how to find a row in multiples files(txt) by criteria(ruc).

the idea is on source set a list:

```
source = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt'....]
ruc= "1804464194001"
row = list(linea.split('\t') for linea in find_by_ruc(source, ruc))
```

**The problem:**

This files has around to 150.000 rows by each file the problem in this case maybe it would be the performance to process this data and find a specific row by criteria. thanks..!!

Comment: use os.walk if all files are in different folders under a sub folder or os.listdir.
you can iterate over the source list and open all the files one by one.
for file in source:
       with open(file) as myfile :

Comment: sorry by don't  specific this..the files are on the same folder/directory

Comment: Why don't you loop over the list elements in `find_by_ruc` if `file` is a `list`?

Comment: the problem maybe it would be the performance to process this data because each file has around 150.000 rows

Comment: for filename in source: find_by_ruc(filename, ruc) # just search one file, then search the next. There's nothing special about multiple files.